# Does Sharepoint 2010 search webpart support danish character?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, search, search-results, fast-search

I am using search webpart (SP 2010). This webpart displayes title and other information. My title contains some danish character, but when I enter Ø or Å  i get ? .

Answer (score 0):

Verify your browser encoding settings are set correctly, e.g., Auto-Select in IE seems to work fine with my Finnish characters, like ÅÄÖ.

Comment: No I still have same problem. I have this problem only in Sharepoint search webpart but not in list or document library.

Comment: Have you modified the search webpart XSLT?